# Reliable cross-browser method of setting and getting the date of a datpicker

Tags: jquery, date, internationalization, cross-browser, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) with which I'm getting and setting the date (which is then serialised to JSON using [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) using the following code:

```
$('#element').datepicker('getDate'); // returns 2012-03-19T00:00:00.000Z
$('#element').datepicker('setDate', value);
```

Unfortunately however this sets the date value in the datpicker to `30/08/2017` under Firefox v11 (which is so far wrong I have no idea where its getting this value from) and `NaN/NaN/NaN` under IE9.

I've tried changing the second line to be the following:

```
$('#element').datepicker('setDate', new Date(value));
```

This then works in Firefox however I still get the same result in IE9.

I then went a bit crazy and started trying to use string manipulation to write and parse dates in some other format in the hope that I would be able to reliably get a simple write / parse scenario to work, but this ended up being a lot more code than I had expected - combined with the fact that I need to take time zones into consideration (in some time zones I might get something like `2012-03-18T23:00:00.000Z` for 2012-03-20, i.e. the date component indicates the date previous) my confidence is currently shaken somewhat as its important that this works across timezones and across browsers.

Is there a reliable method of doing this simple save to JSON load from JSON safely?

- I only care about the date component, not the time component
- The date format itself doesn't really matter as long as it unambigously identifies the date (e.g. I'd like to avoid 01/01/2012 because of ambiguity between US and UK dates).  It would be nice if it were human readable, but if it makes the difference between it working and not I'd rather have it work!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I thought that [getDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) method returns Date object. From there you need to format appropriately, toString() is not an option. In future you would use [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) but right now, you need to use something else, i.e. use getUTCFullYear(), getUTCMonth(), etc. to convert Date into ISO8601 format. Probably there is also some script to do that, but I can't give you the name now.

Comment: @PawełDyda Yes, but `getUTCFullYear()` etc. wont do the trick - for certain time zones that just gives me yesterdays date. I also need to take into account the time component.  I'm also not sure what format to use - the above examples are all in ISO 8601 format but I'm still seeing lots of problem parsing these. I could write my own date parser, however my point is that this is a **lot** of effort for an otherwise extremely simple use-case. There must be a better way!

Comment: getUTC*() methods gives you the actual time in UTC. Time zone offset of course moves this to other date/time, but that's OK unless you want to have today's midnight in given time zone. In this case you can either add time zone offset to the ISO8601 string (instead of putting "Z" which means "Zulu", that is UTC) or use getFullYear(), getMinute() and such, which will give you the date/time in local time zone (in this case you would need to add time offset anyway).

Comment: Instead of parsing the string, you might decide on using Unix time of the epoch, that is number of milliseconds from January 1st, 1970. Date object contains complementary getTime(), setTime() methods, and the constructor Date(milliseconds) which let you do that. It's probably easier way than parsing string. One thing, I don't know though, is if this time is UTC based. You might need to use getTimezoneOffset() as well...

Comment: @PawełDyda the `getUTC*` functions unfortunately gave me the local dates, (at least when I tried it) - I had to adjust the timezone (see my answer below) first otherwise I got the wrong date on certain timeszones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment I have written myself some short JavaScript functions to emit and parse date strings in the ISO8601 format for a date alone (e.g. `2012-03-20`), here they are:

```
/**
* Parses an ISO8601 date string
*/
function parseISODate(str) {
    var dateParts = str.split('-');
    var retVal = new Date;

    retVal.setUTCFullYear(Number(dateParts[0]));
    retVal.setUTCMonth(Number(dateParts[1]) - 1);
    retVal.setUTCDate(Number(dateParts[2]));

    return retVal;
}

/**
* Gets an ISO8601 date string
*/
function iSODateString(d) {
    function pad(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
    }
    return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-'
        + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-'
        + pad(d.getUTCDate());
}
```

As well as this I also need to adjust the date given to me from the date parser back to UTC as otherwise in certain timezones I end up getting yesterdays date:

```
var value = $('#element').datepicker('getDate');
value.setMinutes(value.getMinutes() - value.getTimezoneOffset());
return iSODateString(value); // gives me 2012-03-19

$('#element').datepicker('setDate', parseISODate(value));
```

Amazingly none of the following methods worked when trying to parse dates in the above format:

- The standard IE9 `Date.parse`
- [js-iso860](https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601)
- [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)